# Collapsable toolbar with ImageView inside ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

I have an Activity with following XML

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <fragment android:name=".GalleryFragment"
          android:id="@+id/gallery_fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp"
          android:transitionName="@string/transition">

          ...

    </LinearLayout>
```

GalleryFragment with following XML

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/gallery_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and ViewPager is hosting a couple (max 20) ImageFragments with following XML

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I would like to add collapsable toolbar with parallax effect in such a way that `ImageView` from `ImageFragment` is the one which fades out as it collapses. 
I have done this couple of times on much more simpler screens, I had only activity with toolbar and `ImageView` in it so the process was straightforward. But in this case I have no idea if this is even possible to implement because `ImageView` is inside `Fragment` which is inside `ViewPager`. 
Does anyone know if this is even possible to implement and if so can you give me some tips.

Thanks is advance.